# Python Django custom 404 page not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, http-status-code-404

I have essentially tried 2 solutions here. The first one:
Created 404.HTML inside root templates directory which was supposed to be recognized by Django. By the way have defined it
in `settings.py`:

```
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
```

The second solution I have tried:

In urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import handler404
handler404 = 'pdfapp.views.not_found'
```

in views.py:

```
def not_found(request, exception):
    return render(request, 'partials/not_found.html', status = 404)
```

None of these solutions have worked. Neither YouTube videos nor the other forms could help my case.

###### Note: My DEBUG is set to False

Comment: The 404 handler will only work when debug is False. Set DEBUG to False If you want to test if it's working

Comment: It's already set to False in my project.

Answer (score 0):

to use custom templates for 404, 500 and other error code, there are few steps u must done:

1. add your custom template in any django app (users in example) -> templates folder:

   users/templates/users/404.html
2. add handler for them in urls.py ( public urls )

   handler404 = 'users.views.custom_page_not_found_view'

   handler500 = 'users.views.custom_error_view'
3. add your custom views: users/views.py

```
   def custom_page_not_found_view(request, exception):
   return render(request, "users/404.html", {})


  def custom_error_view(request, exception=None):
    return render(request, "users/500.html", {})
```

4. add debug=False to show the custom pages
5. if you are working on server, then changing debug need service restart: so u must do - in ur case -  `sudo systemctl restart nginx`
   and  `sudo systemctl restart gunicorn`

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, unfortunately it didn't work too. I am making these changes in production(with nginx and gunicorn), but right after make any change i restart both nginx and gunicorn. I suppose it wouldn't make the problem, right?

Comment: try point to a URL not exist in your website, what does it shows ? @Hikmet23

Comment: It shows me default 404 page. Page not found (404)
You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: it seems that u have not change DEBUG on server settings, try change it to DEBUG=False, then restart ur nginx service and gunicorn, and refresh the page, does the page change ?

Comment: Like i have said earlier It's already set to False in .env file.

Comment: update ur question and include snapshot of django project settings hierarchy, so I could help you more... in addition what django version are u using ?

Comment: My current django version is 5.0.1. The 404.html is inside the root templates which i have defined in settings.py 'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates'
        ],

Everything is just fine with middlewares and such. I have especially paid attention to them since i am using i18n

Comment: Thanks for your answer again. But i already restart both nginx and gunicorn after making these changes

Comment: I think you must check your settings, I mean try print(DEBUG) in settings.py or whatever u named it, what does it shows ?
beside of that what is the value of this : DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Comment: In settings.py:DEBUG = getenv("IS_DEVELOPMENT", True). When i write print(DEBUG) in terminal, it gives me False value

Answer (score 0):

I have solved issue by displaying 404 page from nginx itself. In default file of nginx:

```
server{
listen 80;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://my_ip:8000;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
}

location /static{
        autoindex off;
        alias /home/quizuser/main_project/staticfiles/;
}

location /media{
        alias /home/quizuser/uploads/;
}

error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    root /home/quizuser/nginx_error_pages;
    internal;
}

}
```

The i have created a new 404.html page inside directory nginx_error_pages. After these configurations it worked just fine.